# Existence of a fixed-point free map in a manifold.

Tags: manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, vector-fields

I'm having some to proof a question. I have to show that a compact manifold that admits a nowhere vanishing smooth vector field has a smooth map fixed-point free homotopic to the identity map.

I know that there exists a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms that are smoothly homotopic to the identity, in fact the global flow of this vector field plays this role, since $\theta:\Bbb{R}\times M\to M$ is a smooth left-action.

My question is: How can I show that exists $t_0\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $\theta_{t_0}$ has no fixed points? (Here $\theta_{t_0}(x)=\theta(t_0,x)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193940/existence-of-a-fixed-point-free-map-in-a-manifold

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe this kind of qquestion is more apropriate here, do you have some hint to help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given $x \in M$, use the rectification theorem to prove there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\theta(t, y) \neq y$ for all $y \in U$ and for all $0 < |t| < \varepsilon$. Use compactness to extend the result to $M$.

Comment: By the rectification theorem I know that there exists a chart $(\phi,U)$ about $x$ where the vector field $V$ has a canonical representation in the sense that $$V_pf = \partial_1|_p f\circ\phi^{-1},\quad\forall f\in C^\infty(M),\forall p\in U.$$ As such, the integral curve passing through each $p\in U$ has a local representation as $$\gamma_p(t):\mathcal D_p\ni t\mapsto\phi^{-1}(p+te_1)\in M$$ where $\mathcal D_p$ denotes the domain of $t$. Clearly $\mathcal D_p$ depends on $t$, so how to obtain a *uniform* $\epsilon$ for *all* $p\in U$?

Comment: I meant $\mathcal D_p$ depends on $p$, not $t$, sorry for the typo.

Comment: It requires a little more work! Given your chart $(\phi,U)$, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_{2\varepsilon}(\phi(x)) \subset \phi(U)$. For all $p \in \phi^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(\phi(x))) \subset U$ the map $t \in [0,\varepsilon) \to \phi^{-1}(\phi(p) + te_1) \in U$ is an integral curve of $V$. Hence, $[0,\varepsilon) \subset \mathcal{D}_p$. Note the "$U$" in my answer is actually the $\phi^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(\phi(x)))$ I constructed above.

Comment: Yes I just came to think about this shrinking argument too! *Les grands esprits se rencontrent*. :)